# Docker Compose Static Ip addressing

Tags: linux, docker, networking, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy an application with a static ip address and a single network using docker-compose (file format version 3.8), I am able to create them but the ip address is not being correctly assigned to the Container.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:

  nzbhydra2:
    image: linuxserver/nzbhydra2
    container_name: nzbhydra2
    networks:
      mediacenter_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
    ports:
      - "5076:5076"
    volumes:
      - /opt/docker/plex/config:/config
      - /opt/docker/jackett/downloads:/downloads

networks:

    mediacenter_network:
      ipam:
        driver: default
        config:
          - subnet: "172.16.238.0/24"
            gateway: 172.16.238.1
```

The resulting Network Settings from that are as follows:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "0fab46506aeab52588e2b84e676202150b7016c9be49e7958bf9e367f0bd069d",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5076/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5076"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/0fab46506aea",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "compose_mediacenter_network": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {
                        "IPv4Address": "172.16.238.10"
                    },
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "nzbhydra2",
                        "47aad4695014"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "c5953a22f478497c72036bafef32be639200ad69fb37403a6ceb8d23b2ba28d0",
                    "EndpointID": "6138c474befd3449b4c274021bfe212e0dc9ea3e6fd0840171048b5d38b33a11",
                    "Gateway": "172.16.238.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.16.238.10",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 24,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:10:ee:0a",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
```

Notice the ip address is not being assigned in " "IPAddress": "","

I want it to look like if I was doing it manually, example:

```
docker create \
  --name=nzbhydra2_manual_create \
  --restart=always \
  -e PUID=1000 \
  -e PGID=1000 \
  -p 5077:5076 \
  -v /opt/docker/plex/config:/config \
  -v /opt/docker/jackett/downloads:/downloads \
  linuxserver/nzbhydra2
```

Doing it this way, I can see the ip address being assigned in Network Settings:

```
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "2c55f7b547827ef3c9db0299875bfb0c630d407e882ec43011025fcd2b6e6f3b",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5076/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5077"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/2c55f7b54782",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "23442bcbcf2d2f48b1109d92187e5596989f59fdf26c75784b5027ff52593a72",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "34eef2e62215d1bb10f7513207d4d105ed717dc8d1fed48c180cee7ed75cbaab",
                    "EndpointID": "23442bcbcf2d2f48b1109d92187e5596989f59fdf26c75784b5027ff52593a72",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
```

This is how they look like in Portainer:

**Manually Created:**
[image]

**Created with Compose:**
[image]

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong in the Docker Compose file?

Comment: Why are you doing wrong? Does the internet connection inside the container work?

Comment: I added more Containers but they cannot communicate between them inside the same network, but I if create them manually they are able to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was not doing anything wrong, the issue here was that Docker CE is officially not supported on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 8 or CentOS 8. I should have mentioned I was deploying the Containers on CentOS 8, anyway, below you can find the solution.

https://serverfault.com/questions/987686/no-network-connectivity-to-from-docker-ce-container-on-centos-8